# What is the proper technique for using a flame weeder?

Tags: weed-control, tools

How do I use a propane flame weeder in my garden? I want to use it to keep weeds under control but I do not want to harm my vegetables.

Comment: You point it at your gardener, and tell your gardener it will be turned on if he/she does not remove all the weeds without harming the vegetables.  May also work if you have children…

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These weeders are best used between stepping stones and in brick walks. In a vegetable garden, the safest way to use them would be on the paths between raised beds. This tool is made for killing the weeds that come up in walks, patios, driveways, and in crevices in between hard nonflammable surfaces where hand weeding would be very difficult. If you have your vegetables spaced far apart and there is no dry plant matter on the ground, you could use it between them. Be careful not to get too near the vegetables. You may want to water the garden when you are finished because of soil dehydration. It might be faster just to use a hoe.

Comment: Though effective in *killing* the current weeds, this is, at best, a last ditch effort. Burning weeds does not necessarily kill the root system. I suggest the manual labor effort with a hoe.